# AJAX / ASP - Simple Task But I'm stuck?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I'm trying to do a simple AJAX call to an ASP page, that resets session variables and posts a little message back on completion. I'm doing this purely to learn AJAX.

The example came from W3 Schools website but since applying it to my page, I can't seem to get it to work and it's not producing any errors, which is annoying, because I can't debug it.

This is my JS, which is called when a user hits a button [Clear Form]:

```
function resetSearchForm()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById('notification').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","clearSearchData.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();

document.searchFrm.searchStr.value='';
document.searchFrm.vertical.checked = true;
document.searchFrm.horizontal.checked = true;
document.getElementById('dateRange').selectedIndex = 0;
document.searchFrm.searchStr.focus();
}
```

And this is the ASP (clearSearchData.asp) that clears my session variables and writes a message:

```
Response.Expires = -1
Session("search-str-boolean") = ""
Session("search-str-plain") = ""
Session("date-range") = ""
Session("date-from") = ""
Session("date-to") = ""
Session("specificDate") = ""
Session("peopleStr") = ""
Session("orientation") = ""

Response.Write "Form has been reset"
```

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? I have been looking at it for a long time and I just can't see it.

The function itself works because the last part of the function gets processed, the bit that clears the form values... but... the AJAX call doesn't happen because the session variables still contain data and the message doesn't appear.

Many thanks in advance...

---

**UPDATE - - - - - - - - - - -**

It now works. The problem was I didn't include the full URL to the ASP page. Thanks for 'thedaian' (below) for pointing that out

Comment: Stick an alert("something") line somewhere in the onreadystatechange function to see if it's actually getting called.  Alteratively, debug using Firebug or modern browser developer tools.  Obligatory use jquery comment.

Comment: I added an alert() in the 'onreadystatechange' function and it fired, so I assume AJAX has worked

Comment: Stupid question, but I must ask: do you have an element with id 'notification' to display the ajax response?

Comment: Yes bfavaretto, there is that element on my page. It's not a stupid question, it has been known before :) My AJAX works, the ASP page does not do anything. I just added an email script to the ASP page but did not send an email when the AJAX called it

Comment: I've just worked out that AJAX is calling OK but the 'readyState' is not 4 and the status is not 200. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: What's returned when you run the asp page alone in browser ?

Comment: It's now working. All because I didn't add the full URL to the ASP page!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, something is wrong with the page you're trying to get via AJAX.  Check what `xmlhttp.status` is, if it's 404, then you're never going to get to the point where you're printing the AJAX response.  Make sure that `"clearSearchData.asp"` is accessible from the same directory as your javascript. This is a common problem if you have your javascript code in a separate folder from the rest of your site.  Or simply put in the full URL path for the `"clearSearchData.asp"` so it'll definitely work.

Something to point out, the function in `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is (usually) called *after* it's declared in the code.  In this case, it gets called after your search form fields are cleared out and reset.

Comment: Thanks thedaian. I have got a 404 error, you're right, I'm trying hard to pin-point the exact problem but struggling

Comment: Good to know that it worked!  It's probably worth checking out jQuery, which makes ajax a one line function, or at least using the developer tools in most modern browsers. (It's useful to do this stuff yourself at least once, but something like jQuery is useful for bigger projects)

Comment: Thanks, I will read in to that. I'm glad I did it this way first because I understand how it works now. I'm self-taught and have been dreading learning AJAX but it seems pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call does not automatically send along a session cookie. That means the session you're clearing is not the user's session, but just a session that's been created for that ajax call alone.

Comment: Thanks Menno. But surely the Response.Write "Message" would appear even if the Session variables didn't clear?

Comment: True enough, it should. Have you tried using Fiddler to see what's being returned from your ajax call?